# Deleting duplicate dictionaries in a list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists of dictionaries

```
list1 = [ {..}, {..}, ..]
list2 = [ {..}, {..}, ..]
```

I want to remove the dictionaries in list1 which are in list2. I had a similar problem where I had a list of lists instead of a dictionary and it is solved here

[python function slowing down for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723494/python-function-slowing-down-for-no-apparent-reason)

If I use the same code which is,

```
def removeDups(list1, list2):
    list2_set = set([tuple(x) for x in list2])
    diff = [x for x in list1 if tuple(x) not in list2_set]

    return diff
```

I do not get correct results since dictionaries like

```
{key1:'a', key2:'b'} and 
{key2:'b', key1:'a'}
```

which are the same are actually considered as different. How can I change the code or what can I do to remove dictionaries from list1 that appear in list2?

Comment: each dict has the same keys and same associated values. its just the order of the keys when printed that are different in the two examples I gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `dict`s in `set`s because they're mutable and don't have stable identities. You can work around that by making a `tuple` out of their items. Note that simply wrapping a `dict` in a `tuple` doesn't get around the fact that distinct `dict`s will still appear to be distinct objects even if they contain the same items.

To turn two "equivalent" `dict`s into equal objects, take all of their items, sort the items, and then stuff them into a `tuple`: `tuple(sorted(map.items()))`. Those `tuple`s will properly compare equal to each other if they contain the same items, no matter the order of the original `dict`.

```
def removeDups(list1, list2):
    set1 = set(tuple(sorted(x.items())) for x in list1)
    set2 = set(tuple(sorted(x.items())) for x in list2)

    return set1 - set2
```

Comment: Just remember, this version will work for lists of dictionaries, not lists of lists :)

Comment: @gnud Thanks for the answer to the last problem I posted. Worked like a charm.