# Python 3.3 Slowing Down During Large Loop

Tags: performance, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I am fairly new to programming and do not understand the reason for the slowdown in my program.

I am working with data sets of about 350,000 - 500,000 rows and would appreciate some direction.

I need to check all entries in a new list against the old in order to update the old entries as well as add the completely new entries to the the end of the list.

If a print statement is added to the reassignment loop and the new line exception the first few thousand iterations are fast but after that the program becomes very slow. (almost 1000 complete loops in the first 3 seconds, after about the 20,000th iteration the speed has reduced to slower than 100 complete loops in 5 seconds and by the 60,000th iteration it is slower than 100 complete loops in 15 seconds.)

RAM is less than 70% usage and CPU has held constant between 48 and 50%

The code looks like this:

```
import gc
gc.disable() #this was added to possibly improve speed

def updateOldList(oldListOfLists, newListOfLists):
    oldListIndexDict = dict()
    IDNumber = <index of ID number>
    for i in range(len(oldListOfLists)):
        oldListIndexDict[oldList[i][IDNumber]] = i
    for i in range(len(newListOfLists)):
        try:
            oldIndex = oldListIndexDict[newListOfLists[i][IDNumber]]
            oldListOfLists[oldIndex][0] = newListOfLists[i][0]
            oldListOfLists[oldIndex][3] = newListOfLists[i][3]
            del(oldListIndexDict[newListOfLists[i][IDNumber]]) #this was added to limit the number of entries in the hash table to attempt to improve speed
        except:
            oldListOfLists= oldListOfLists + newListOfLists
return oldListOfLists
```

The inner lists in each of the lists of lists need to remain ordered so I don't think I can use sets.

The following two questions were very similar enough that I tried/ considered their comments before asking.

[python function slowing down for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723494/python-function-slowing-down-for-no-apparent-reason)

[Python function slows down with presence of large list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823465/python-function-slows-down-with-presence-of-large-list)

Comment: What if you remove `gc.disable()`? The same?

Comment: That is the way I had it originally, there was a minor gain by adding it.

Comment: Don't use a bare except: clause, list exactly what you want to catch to avid hiding bugs.  My concern at first glance would be that your old = old+new line is copying and destroying larger and larger lists every loop iteration.  Use old.extend(new) instead.

Comment: This solved the issue. I would mark the question answered if you resubmit this as an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let's work with Python 3.3.
I suppose for each list in *oldListOfLists* should be one in *newListOfLists*, and you mostly update the values, so, for instance, the 0th of the *oldListOfLists* is updated by the 0th of the *newListOfLists*, the 1ft and so on- the same index, you could simplify your code.

```
def updateOldList(oldListOfLists, newListOfLists):

    for i in range(lenNewListOfLists):
        try:            
            oldListOfLists[i][0] = newListOfLists[i][0]
            oldListOfLists[i][3] = newListOfLists[i][3]            
        except IndexError:
            oldListOfLists+=newListOfLists

return oldListOfLists
```

If the a list from *oldListofLists* isn't updated by one with the same index in the *newListOfLists*, it actually won't work well, you can imagine it.

Edit: you might want to catch something like IndexError, in case there's no corresponding old list for the active new list, but not the others, general errors.

Edit2 :   += is an alias for extend.

```
oldListOfLists+=newListOfLists
```

is the same as

```
oldListOfLists.extend(newListOfLists)
```

Edit3 : do the code still slows down? Do your last lists (in index) get bigger and bigger?
What is the overall memory size of both lists of lists?